# Why is the text not indented here?

Tags: packages, indentation

Something in this part is causing a indentation problem here. It seems like `parskip` is the cause here.

```
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\newcommand*{\permcomb}[4][0mu]{{{}^{#3}\mkern#1#2_{#4}}}
\newcommand*{\perm}[1][-3mu]{\permcomb[#1]{P}}
\newcommand*{\comb}[1][-1mu]{\permcomb[#1]{C}}
\usepackage{booktabs,capt-of}
\usepackage{newtxtext, newtxmath}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}   % it load graphicx too
```

If I remove this part then it is indented as expected. What is the problem here? How can I fix it? 
I read and it seems `parskip` is a good thing to keep so can I keep both the indentation and the package?

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[caption=false,font=normalsize,labelfont=sf,textfont=sf]{subfig}
\usepackage{stfloats}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{cite}
\hyphenation{op-tical net-works semi-conduc-tor IEEE-Xplore}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\newcommand*{\permcomb}[4][0mu]{{{}^{#3}\mkern#1#2_{#4}}}
\newcommand*{\perm}[1][-3mu]{\permcomb[#1]{P}}
\newcommand*{\comb}[1][-1mu]{\permcomb[#1]{C}}
\usepackage{booktabs,capt-of}
\usepackage{newtxtext, newtxmath}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}   % it load graphicx too
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{stfloats} % 


\begin{document}
\section{Introduction}
This is the first line of a section but why is it not indented here? 

The same for this, it is not indented even when I leave one empty line above. How can I fix this?
\end {document}
```

Comment: the main thing the parskip package does is remove indentation (along with adding vertical skip) why did you add the package if you want paragraphs marked by indentation?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I'm not quite sured about that. Probably I copied someone code and keep that.

Comment: You should only include packages that you intend to use. Just accumulating a larger and larger preamble copying random stuff from earlier documents will surely lead to hard to debug conflicts and unexpected behaviour.

Comment: note while Werner's answer is correct as written, having indentation _and_ vertical space is a rather unusual design. Not loading `parskip` is almost surely what you want here.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I see. Probably I should remove it then.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [`parskip` package](//ctan.org/pkg/parskip) [documentation](//texdoc.net/pkg/parskip):

> The package can be used with any document class at any size. By
> default it produces the following paragraph layout: Zero `\parindent` and
> non-zero `\parskip`.

So, by default it sets `\parindent` to `0pt`. If you want to retain the indent, add the `indent` package option:

```
\usepackage[indent]{parskip}
```

From section **2.1 Options to customize the package**:

> **`indent`**
>
> With the package option `indent` it is possible to explicitly set the paragraph indentation. Using this option without a value keeps the document
> class indentation unchanged, if it is specified with a value then that value
> is used. If the package is loaded without this option the indentation is set
> to zero.